# Swift NSString code bad access

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting bad access in the following NSString code for swift.

```
var queryStr : NSString = NSString(format:user.name!, user.userName!, user.email!)
```

I am not sure why this is to be honest. Here is what the crash exactly says. Is there a reason why this may occur? Maybe it has something to do with my other code. I am using a singleton to access this code and my singleton seems to not be working well at all.

> Thread 1 EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x0)

Comment: maybe you missed something: `NSString(format: @"%@, %@, %@", user.name!, user.userName!, user.email!)`...?

Answer (score 1):

The proper use for this initializer is:

```
var queryStr: NSString = NSString(format:"%@ %@, %@", user.name! user.userName!, user.email!)
```

but in Swift you can use Swift  String and do just:

```
var myString = "\(user.name!), \(user.userName!), \(user.email!)"
```